# How do I reuse an int outside of loop. C#

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I've created code to read a user's number and change it into an int. Essentially my code looks like this

```
while (e != 1)
{
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
e += 1;
}
```

How do I reuse the 'int num' outside of the loop?

Comment: You should declare int num outside your while loop.

Comment: If you mean its value, decleare the `num` at outside of the `while`. If you mean its memory, the runtime should optimize to reuse the memory for another local variable automately for you.

Comment: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/know-scope-local-variables  - this article gives an introduction on the rules of scope of variables in C# - it is useful to know them.

Comment: @rytisk: as well as declaring the variable outside the loop, it needs initialising otherwise the compiler will complain about use of an uninitialised variable outside the loop.

Comment: @PaulF Are you sure? Because I just tried it (without assigning a value) and it worked fine.

Comment: @rytisk: you will receive an error only when you try to do something with the value of `num`, like `int numThreeTimes = num * 3;`. If you just want to re-use the variable itself, like `num = 4;` you will not receive the error.

Comment: @MartinBackasch So in this case - declaring `int num` without initialization just before the `while` loop -  everything will work fine. Since we do assignment to `num` before using it anywhere.

Comment: @rytisk: It depends. May let me explain it with a short example: `int num; while (e != 1) { num = 1; }  num = 3; int numThreeTimes = num * 3` is fine and will compile, because we will assign a value to  num an use it. But when you write `int num; while (e != 1) { num = 1; } int numThreeTimes = num * 3` you will get the mentioned error [CS0165](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165), because it could be happen that you skip the assignment within  `while`. But why the compiler does not use the default 0 of the int num, I can't say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare `num` outside of the loop but **assign** to it inside the loop:

```
int num = 0; // Or some other default value
while (e != 1)
{
    num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // Note that num is NOT declared here
    e += 1;
}
// Use num here
```

Comment: You should highlight that the initialisation to a (default) value MUST be done to avoid compiler errors about use of uninitialised variables outside the loop.

Comment: @PaulF: As state in the comments above. It depends on how you proceed with `num` in the next steps. If you just want to assign a new value to `num` you will not receive the error. If you want to do something with value of `num` you get the error.

Comment: @MartinBackasch : the way I read the question was OP wanted to use the value outside of the loop. If it just reassigned outside the loop, then that is fine.

Comment: @PaulF: Yes you're right, it depends on how _How do I reuse the 'int num' outside of the loop?_ is meant in the question.